# How do I navigate fast through directories with the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, command-line-interface

I spent some time finding a solution for my problem but google couldn't provide me a sufficient answer... I'm working a lot with the command line in linux and I simply need a way to navigate fast through my file system. I don't want to type cd [relative or absoulte path] all the time. I know there is [pushd and popd](https://mhoffman.github.io/2015/05/21/how-to-navigate-directories-with-the-shell.html) but that still seems too complicated for a simple problem like this.

When I'm in `~/Desktop/sampleFile` I simply want to use `sampleCommand fileToGo` to get to `~/Desktop/anotherFile/anotherFile/fileToGo`, no matter, where the file is located. Is there an easy command for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `cdable_vars`  and, in particular, `CDPATH` can help simplifie things for you. Look up their description in the BASH man page. However, finding a directory entry **no matter where it is located** in your file system is virtually impossible to achieve in a reasonable way. You would have to keep an up-to-date index of all directory entries on all mounted file system, and in practice, many of the directory names would be duplicate (nearly every user will likely have his own _bin_  or _tmp_ directory) and most names would be ambiguous.

Comment: Give [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) a try.

Comment: Why using external tools when you can just store all the paths into variables ?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with native Bash features without involving a sub-shell fork:

You can insert this into your `"$HOME/.bashrc"`:

```sh
cdf(){
  # Query globstar state
  shopt -q globstar
  # and save it in the gs variable (gs=0 if set, 1 if not)
  local gs=$?

  # Need globstar to glob find files in sub-directories
  shopt -s globstar

  # Find the file in directories
  # and store the result into the matches array
  matches=(**/"$1")

  # globstar no longer needed, so restore its previous state
  [ $gs -gt 0 ] && shopt -u globstar

  # Change to the directory containing the first matched file
  cd "${matches[0]%/*}" # cd EXIT status is preserved
}
```

Comment: Nice! It might be an idea to save the initial globstar setting and set it back how it was afterwards to avoid surprises later.

Comment: @MarkSetchell implemented `globstar` state restoration

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you could do something like this:

```sh
cd $(dirname $(find . -name name-of-your-file | head -n 1))
```

That will search the current directory (use `/` instead of `.` to search all directories) for a file called `name-of-your-file` and `cd` into the parent directory of the first file with that name that it finds.

If you're in a large directory, typing the path and using `cd` will probably be faster than this, but it works alright for small directories.

Comment: You *could* make that into a `bash` function called `cdf` for `cd **fast**` see https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/

Comment: You commands arguments need double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can try cd++ from here:

https://github.com/vitalij555/cd_plus_plus

Once installed, it's easy to use:

1. Mark your current directory with label(or several labels for convenience):

> mark label_name

2. Return to that folder anytime later by just issuing:

> go label_name

I wrote this script as I usually need to switch between many different folders during the workday and was bored of creating aliases manually.